# Runtime error on during execution of cnn model for image recognition with fastai library

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, conv-neural-network, fast-ai, dataloader

I am training a cnn model to recognise images. However, I get an error when running this code:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)/‘images’

def is_cat(x): return x[0].isupper()
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func(
path, get_image_files(path), valid_pct=0.2, seed=42,
label_func=is_cat, item_tfms=Resize(224))

learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(1)
```

error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 learn.fine_tune(1)

RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 12456, 4440, 3268, 448) exited unexpectedly
```

The error happens at the last line (was a longer error but SO does not let me submit all of that).
I am not running on GPU (as suggested on internet) because I havent really got how to tell jupiter notebook to do that.

Can you help?
Thanks, Luigi

Answer (score 1):

you can add `num_workers=0`
Example

```
ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func(path, files, label_func, item_tfms=Resize(224),**num_workers=0**)
```